# MongoDB Aggregate Issue

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to display all the products ordered in the order with the id of ‘O1234’ using the aggregate function. I've gone over my code multiple times and I keep getting an error saying I've left out a '}' bracket, but I just can't seem to find it.

Below is the code that I've tried for the above query:

```
db.order.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$order"},
    {$unwind: "$order.product"}, 
    {$match: {"order._id": 'O1234'}}, 
    {
        $project: {
            _id:0, 
            prod_name: "$order.product.prod_name",
            prod_price: "$order.product.prod_price", 
            order_qty: "$order.product.order_qty", 
            order_total: $multiply:
            ["$order.product.prod_price", "$order.product.order_qty"]
        }
    }
]);
```

And below is my code for the orders collection, which has an array of products in it:

```
db.order.insert(
    {
        _id: 'O1234',
        date: '2018-02-11',
        time: '09:03',
        cust_id: 'C2057',
        driver: 'Mike',
        products: [
            {   _id: 'P1234', 
                order_qty: 1,
                prod_name: 'Office Desk',
                prod_price: 50
            },
            {
                _id: 'P5678',
                order_qty: 1,
                prod_name: 'Bathroom Cabinet',
                prod_price: 30
            }
        ]
    }
);
db.order.insert(
    {
        _id: 'O5678',
        date: '2018-06-10',
        time: '07:30',
        cust_id: 'C2018',
        driver: 'Jack',
        products: [
            {
                _id: 'P1122', 
                order_qty: 5,
                prod_name: 'Outdoor Chair',
                prod_price: 65
            },
            {
                _id: 'P3344',
                order_qty: 3,
                prod_name: 'Dining Table',
                prod_price: 90
            },
            {
                _id: 'P5566',
                order_qty: 7,
                prod_name: 'Bathroom Cabinet',
                prod_price: 30
            },
        ]
    }
);
db.order.insert(
    {
        _id: 'O4321',
        date: '2018-11-07',
        time: '06:00',
        cust_id: 'C0987',
        driver: 'Jack',
        products: [
            {
                _id: 'P3344', 
                order_qty: 10,
                prod_name: 'Outdoor Chair',
                prod_price: 65
            }
        ]
    }
);
db.order.insert(
    {
        _id: 'O8765',
        date: '2017-08-19',
        time: '11:30',
        cust_id: 'C2018',
        driver: 'Mike',
        products: [
            {
                _id: 'P1234', 
                order_qty: 2,
                prod_name: 'Office Desk',
                prod_price: 50
            }
        ]
    }
);
db.order.insert(
    {
        _id: 'O2018',
        date: '2018-02-11',
        time: '20:43',
        cust_id: 'C1849',
        driver: 'Mike',
        products: [
            {
                _id: 'P1122', 
                order_qty: 10,
                prod_name: 'Outdoor Chair',
                prod_price: 65
            },
            {
                _id: 'P5678',
                order_qty: 2,
                prod_name: 'Bathroom Cabinet',
                prod_price: 30
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it `$multiply:
["$order.product.prod_price", "$order.product.order_qty"]` should be in `{}`

Comment: To be clearer that's `order_total: { $multiply:` where you have `order_total: $multiply:`. So that's where the brace is missing.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid when I try that, I get an error message: 'invalid property id'.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have indented my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think for multiply syntax would be like that mentioned below

```
total: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] }
```

For more help please refer to below link
[Syntax for multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't print out anything at all, not even an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Others have helped you with the syntax error in your `$multiply`, but the bigger problem is that your `$` prefixed field names are all wrong. You don't have an `orders` level of your documents and the products array is named `products`, not `product`.

You should also put your `$match` filter first in the pipeline as it's more efficient to filter before the unwind.

```
db.order.aggregate([
    {$match: {"_id": 'O1234'}}, 
    {$unwind: "$products"}, 
    {
        $project: {
            _id:1, 
            prod_name: "$products.prod_name",
            prod_price: "$products.prod_price", 
            order_qty: "$products.order_qty", 
            order_total: {$multiply: ["$products.prod_price", "$products.order_qty"]}
        }
    }
]);
```